# Free char pointer in C language

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have the following function which reads in the graph. When I am running Valgrind I am getting following error:

```
definitely lost: 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks
```

I am allocating 1048576 bytes using `char * line = malloc(1024 * 1024)` but in the end, I am freeing line pointer. What am I doing wrong here?

```
pr_graph * pr_graph_load(
char const * const ifname)
{
 FILE * fin = fopen(ifname, "r");
 pr_graph * graph = malloc(sizeof(*graph));

 char * line = malloc(1024 * 1024);
 size_t len = 0;

 /* Read in graph one vertex at a time. */
 for(pr_int v=0; v < graph->nvtxs; ++v) {
ssize_t read = getline(&line, &len, fin);
if(read == -1) {
  free(line);
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: premature EOF at line %lu\n", v+1);
  pr_graph_free(graph);
  return NULL;
}

/* Store the beginning of the adjacency list. */
graph->xadj[v] = edge_ptr;

/* Check for sinks -- these make pagerank more difficult. */
if(read == 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: vertex '%lu' is a sink vertex.\n", v+1);
  continue;
}

/* Foreach edge in line. */
char * ptr = strtok(line, " ");
while(ptr != NULL) {
  char *end = NULL;
  pr_int const e_id = strtoull(ptr, &end, 10);
  /* end of line */
  if (ptr == end) {
    break;
  }
  assert(e_id > 0 && e_id <= graph->nvtxs);

  graph->nbrs[edge_ptr++] = e_id - 1; /* 1 indexed */
  ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
 }
 assert(edge_ptr == graph->nedges);
 graph->xadj[graph->nvtxs] = graph->nedges;

 free(line);
 fclose(fin);

 return graph;
```

Comment: It looks like you are freeing what you are allocating, even if the routine fails, so the next question is: are you sure *this* is the routine that fails to correctly free all memory? Disable this routine and run your code; does valgrind still report the same memory loss?

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes I am sure this is the routine. I disabled it and the error was gone. Is strtok function responsible for this?

Comment: No – or, at least, it *should* not. But ... here is another possible reason for valgrind reporting such errors: you may be overwriting important information in this routine. Is it correct that `.. malloc(sizeof(*graph));` only allocates *one* item, with the size of a *pointer*, rather than `sizeof(graph)` itself? (We cannot tell from the snippet of code, which may be the very reason for the downvotes and closevotes.)

Comment: @usr2564301 - given the amount of memory I am guessing the issue is with `line` as the memory lost looks like `1024*1024`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misusing the POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function.  You have:

```
char * line = malloc(1024 * 1024);
size_t len = 0;

/* Read in graph one vertex at a time. */
for(pr_int v=0; v < graph->nvtxs; ++v)
{
    ssize_t read = getline(&line, &len, fin);
```

You tell `getline()` there are zero bytes allocated, so it allocates more space in `line` — it is under no obligation to `free()` line before doing so.

> ```
> ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n,
>        FILE *restrict stream);
> ```
>
> The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function. If `*n` is non-zero, the application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an object of size at least `*n` bytes, or is a null pointer.

Your code meets the '`*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to `free()`' criterion; but you set `*n` to zero so the second condition isn't relevant.  Since `*n` says "there is no memory allocated yet", it will ignore the value in `*lineptr`.

You should be using one of these:

```
char * line = 0;
size_t len = 0;

/* Read in graph one vertex at a time. */
for(pr_int v=0; v < graph->nvtxs; ++v)
{
    ssize_t read = getline(&line, &len, fin);
```

or:

```
size_t len = 1024 * 1024;
char * line = malloc(size);

/* Read in graph one vertex at a time. */
for(pr_int v=0; v < graph->nvtxs; ++v)
{
    ssize_t read = getline(&line, &len, fin);
```

Either will work.  I'd probably use the empty buffer — I don't often allocate 1 MiB of space up front unless I know it will all be used.

Be aware that with the null pointer and zero length, `getline()` will typically allocate space even if the file is empty and it immediately returns `-1`.  You should take steps to free it.  Since `line` is null, even if `getline()` doesn't allocate space, `line` can be passed to `free()` safely.

If you are compiling correctly (compile *and* link with the `-g` option), Valgrind will tell you which line allocated the leaked memory.  If you don't get that information, you are misusing Valgrind (or, at least, under-using it — it can tell you so much more if you let it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to disable this line

```
ssize_t read = getline(&line, &len, fin);
```

It is a guess, but I think that `line` is being modified by `getline`...

so if you run the code without it then you will see with `valgrind` if that is where the problem lies.

If that is the answer is there anyway you can have a smaller amount of memory for `line` and define it with

```
char line [100000];
```

then you wouldn't have the same memory issue I think...

Comment: That line and a couple of its predecessors are the problem; the fix isn't what's needed, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thanks for another helpful comment - at this point I will delete my answer as yours is so much better...